# How to use ffmpeg to encode a file with possible error?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have a video file, which contains some error. The file is readable, but possible some blocks are wrong during some disk operation. So while playing the video, a few seconds will no be displayed correctly. Most media player will let me play this file without crash.

Now I want to use ffmpeg to encode the file into some other format. But the re-encode process is blocked by that error.

I want to know if there's anyway to let ffmpeg to ignore that error, just like the media players. It can just ignore/skip that few seconds, and continue working on the rest.

Comment: The player might have different error concealment methods. To my knowledge, there's no such option. If the stream is incorrectly parsed, FFmpeg will rather quit than produce garbage. Can you add the full output log of such a conversion you're trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution I found, is to use the `-ss` option to skip the place that have errors.