# Prevent ffmpg from concealing errors during conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm experimenting with using Audacity to create glitch videos (datamosh and databend are synonyms). So, I create an AVI, pull it into Audacity as raw data, manipulate the stream, and the save it back out as an AVI. I'm on a Mac, so I'd like to use `ffmpeg` to convert the AVI over to an MP4 for uploading, sharing, etc.

The problem I'm running into is that `ffmpeg` automatically detects data errors and truncates the video during conversion. Here's a snippet from the terminal output:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fe81b9bbc00] ac-tex damaged at 43 21
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fe81b9bbc00] Error at MB: 1198
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fe81b9bbc00] concealing 114 DC, 114 AC, 114 MV errors in I frame
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fe81b9c1a00] Error at MB: 540
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fe81b9c1a00] ac-tex damaged at 25 10
```

Now, the catch is, I *want* those errors in the video.

Is there a way to prevent `ffmpeg` from concealing those errors during transcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ffmpeg to encode a file with possible error?](http://superuser.com/questions/556192/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-encode-a-file-with-possible-error)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because his issue was `ffmpeg` quitting during the conversion. The program will convert the entire video, but it removes the damaged sections. The `-ss` flag will note sections to skip so it doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is not to convert/process actual A/V data, but to repack from AVI to MP4, you should add "-codec copy" to your command line